# How to install an application without some dependencies?

Tags: software-installation, kvm-virtualization, qemu, multisystem

I want to install Multisystem:

```
wget -q http://liveusb.info/multisystem/depot/multisystem.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add - 
sudo apt-get install multisystem
```

But it automaticly installs Qemu/Kvm and some Virtualbox stuff, how to prevent this?

Comment: You cannot prevent this. What is the problem to install the dependencies?

Comment: The *problem* is that  I can't use and don't need virtualization-tools on my system because it hasn't got enough resources
and these packages are getting updated very often so I always have to download them.

Comment: But these packages are needed for `multisystem` according to its developers. So there is no choice. You can rebuild deb without these dependencies, but most likely the program will not work.

Comment: Some time ago I built it from source without these packages and it just worked fine ... but I missed the updates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get -d install multisystem
cd /var/cache/apt/archives
ls *.deb
```

Then you can manually install individual packages:

```
dpkg --ignore-depends=unwanted-package.deb,another-unwanted.deb -i package.deb
```

Note that this is a way to **install software without dependiences, not to make it work properly without dependiences.**